# Python Type Error while printing

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to convert psuedocode; I got a Type error, but I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. I've tried changing things, but I'm not sure which bit of it is wrong.

```
  File "C:\Users\ClassyMelon\Downloads\mrocedures.py", line 46, in Menu
    DisplayWeight(Type, Weight, Volume)
  File "C:\Users\ClassyMelon\Downloads\mrocedures.py", line 24, in DisplayWeight
    print (str(Volume)), "g", "of", Metals[Type], "weighs",  Weight, "g"
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Code:

```
def GetVolume():
    print ("How many cubic cm of water does the item displace?")
    Volume = input("")
    while Volume == "":
       print ("You must input a value")
       Volume = input("")
return float(Volume)

def DisplayDensities():
    Densities = ["19.32", "10.49", "21.45"]
    Metals = ["Gold", "Silver", "Platimun"]
    for Counter in range(3):
        Msg = 'Density of ' + Metals[Counter]
        Msg = Msg + ' is ' + str(Densities[Counter]) + 'g per cubic cm'
        print (Msg)

def CalcWeight(Density, Volume):
     Weight = Density * Volume
     return Weight

def DisplayWeight(Type, Weight, Volume):
    WeightAsString = str(Weight)
    Metals = ["Gold", "Silver", "Platimun"]
    print (str(Volume)), "g", "of", Metals[Type], "weighs",  Weight, "g"

def Menu():
    DisplayDensities()
    print ("Choose an option Below:")
    print ("a) Calculate wieght of Gold")
    print ("b) Calculate wieght of Silver")
    Answer = input()
    Volume = GetVolume()
    if Answer == "a":
        Density = 19.32
        Type = "Gold"
    elif Answer == "b":
        Density = 10.49
        Type = "Silver"
    elif Answer == "b":
        Density = 21.45
        Type = "Platimun"    
    elif Answer !="a" or "b" or "c":
        print ("You must input 'a', 'b' or 'c'.")
        Menu()
    Weight = CalcWeight(Density, Volume)
    DisplayWeight(Type, Weight, Volume)
Menu()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
Menu()
```

Comment: `Metals` is a list, `Type` is a string - what did you expect `Metals[Type]` to do, exactly? Also, you should really read the style guide: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: The stacktrace is quite explicit: you wrote `Metals[Type]` but `Type` is a string and should be an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code is the problem:

```
print (str(Volume)), "g", "of", Metals[Type], "weighs",  Weight, "g"
```

Specifically, it's the `Metals[Type]` piece.  `Metals` is a list, and lists are accessed via integer indexes, i.e. `Metals[0]` or `Metals[5]`.  But in your code, `Type` is a string, and you can't use a string as a list index.

Comment: This answer contains no information that wasn't in the traceback!

Comment: ... and clearly the OP didn't *understand* the traceback, so what point are you trying to make?

Comment: But you aren't actually *explaining* anything, you're using basically the same words the error message does; if the OP didn't understand the traceback, why would they understand this?

Comment: I disagree that I'm not *explaining* anything.

Answer (score 0):

Type is a string: in fact it is already one of "Gold", "Silver" or "Platimun"(!). So there is no point looking it up in a list consisting of those same strings.